# Centos7: awk supporting utf16le?

Tags: linux, centos, awk, unicode

I know it awk can handle utf8, however, this requires a duplex conversion step using iconv

Say something like:

```
 iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 "$file" > "$fileTmp"
 #Perform operation 
 awk -F\| {print $1} $fileTmp > $awkFile
 iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16 "$awkFile" > "$file"
```

My issue with this is when I need to handle several multi-gig files that are in an ETL process. Figuring it takes 100 seconds to handle the round trip per file over 10 folders that have 200+ files that conversion adds up really quick!

Is there a version of AWK or an extended version that can handle UTF16LE natively?

Comment: Your description makes it sound like most of the time is wasted in disk trashing. You will probably achieve acceptable performance if you pipe your file through `iconv`, `awk` and back through `iconv` instead of going through temporary files.

Comment: @kmkaplan Since the servers are in Azure with SSD storage I was less concerned but it may be worth running it through pipe to measure the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a locale that uses UTF-16 on a POSIX system as that's not compatible with the C locale.

With GNU `awk`, you may be able to do:

```
LC_ALL=C awk -v RS='\n\0' -v ORS='\n\0' -F '[|]\0' '{print $1}'
```

That is, treat the input as a stream of bytes, but set the record and field separators as their two byte UTF-16LE encodings.

Now, that wouldn't work if properly if the input contains things like:

```
<U+0AFF><U+FF00>
```

Which would be encoded as `FF0A00FF` (so contains the `\n\0` record separator).

Converting to UTF-8 seems like the only reliable option. You don't need to use a temp file though (here assuming the locale's charmap is UTF-8)

```
< file.in iconv -f UTF-16LE |
  awk -F'|' '{print $1}' |
  iconv -t UTF-16LE > file.out
```

Since no other character than `|` in UTF-8 can contain the byte for `|` (0x7c) (same for newline or any character in the portable character set), you can also optimise by using the C locale for `awk` or even use `cut`:

```
< file.in iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 |
  LC_ALL=C cut -d '|' -f1 |
  iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16LE > file.out
```

Comment: Actually you *could* have a locale using UTF-16, and the mention of POSIX is irrelevant in that context.  You might want to improve your explanation, using the assumptions built into many applications.

Comment: @ThomasDickey. POSIX more or less mandates all the characters in the portable character set to be single byte and be invariant across all locales supported on the system. That precludes UTF-16.

Comment: I will accept this as the answer. I did try using gawk and the performance dropped 300% in the runtime of each file so under the hood something odd is happening. Good to know more about the why in this case before changing the scripts :)